# When will Apple start rejecting apps built with Xcode 5.x?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

We are still working with Xcode 5 builds for certain things. Now that Xcode 7 is out we fear soon builds with Xcode 5.x+ will not be accepted in the store. Do we know a deadline for that?

Answer (score 0):

No date has been released yet, but January/February 2015 was the deadline for building against the iOS8 SDK for new apps this year (and 64-bit).

Comment: Thanks! I already had this information. I am looking for Xcode 5.x deprecation.